# How to separate date-time stamp into 2 columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a column containing two different datetime formats that I'm trying to split into a standardised column. The two formats are as such:

```
21/09/2017 7:39
14/07/17 13:47
```

I've tried splitting out the datetime components individually, but it appears the YEAR function doesn't like parsing the two digit dates. As a ghetto workaround, I've done a find and replace, but this isn't sustainable. Any excel geniuses out there have any ideas or functions I should be looking at?

Cheers

Comment: If find replace works then your dates are text that look like dates and not true dates.  Parse the strings to get them to true dates and format them all the same.

Comment: Have you tries *Text-to-Columns* to see if it will give you a standard *datetime* format?

Comment: Please could you re title this question to reflect what you're actually asking?

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's a terrible subject. I'll try and fix that up.

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanted a VBA response to your question, here it is.

You will need to make adjustments to your range, as this is only going to pull off of `A1` (you didn't specify the original range with the text dates, nor the ranges of the new date and times).

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitDateAndTime()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim RawVal As String, RawDate As String, RawTime As String
    RawVal = ws.Range("A1").Value
    RawDate = Split(RawVal, " ")(0)
    RawTime = Split(RawVal, " ")(1)

    Dim NewDate As Date, NewTime As Date
    NewDate = CDate(RawDate)
    NewTime = CDate(RawTime)

    ws.Range("A1") = NewDate
    ws.Range("B1") = NewTime

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing. This is great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

***Please note this formula assumes all of your dates will be after the year 2000. If that's not true, let me know and I'll figure something else out.***

It looks like your first date is being recognised as a proper datetime, while your second is a text value.

Here is what I've worked out:

[image: Screenshot 1]

There is an `=IFERROR` formula in both the Date and Time columns. The first formula in each works on the datetime format, and the second works on the text format and can be dragged down to work on any cell reference.

This is the formula in B1:

```
=IFERROR(DATE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy"),TEXT(A2,"mm"),TEXT(A2,"dd")), DATE(MID(MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,5),FIND("/",MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,5))+1,2)+2000,MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,2),LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1)))
```

And this is the formula in C1:

```
=IFERROR(TIME(TEXT(A2,"hh"),TEXT(A2,"mm"),0),TIME(LEFT(MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)-2,5),FIND(":",MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)-2,5))-1),MID(MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)-2,5),FIND(":",MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)-2,5))+1,256),0))
```

Comment: No worries lolh4x ! Feel free to give my answer an upvote or choose it as your chosen answer if you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the Date assuming that your data in on column A

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

T0 get the Time assuming that your data in on column A

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,5))
```